# xclock Reverts to 12 Hour

Tags: command-line, xorg

- Linux 4.10.0-35-generic
- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- I use X and TWM

I start `xclock` with:

```
/usr/bin/xclock -digital -twentyfour -update 1 -geometry 230x30-1+1 &
```

The next day, xclock reverts to twelve hour.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 I didn't even know such an app exists. Awesomeness.

Comment: From `man xclock`, we have "-digital or -d :: This option indicates that a 24 hour digital clock should be used." and we also have "-twentyfour :: This option indicates that a digital clock should display the time in twenty-four hour format.  This is the default when a  digital  clock  is used." Maybe you don't need to use both at the same time...

Comment: Are you sure that it reverts to 12 hours the next day? You might not notice any difference until the afternoon. -- Anyway, I will check it in my computer ...

Comment: Yes, I am sure it reverts to 12 hour format.  It indicates 3...PM in the afternoon!

Comment: `xclock` now runs for 48 hours with your command on my machine and doesn't revert to 12-hour format. To file a bug please read [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).